# weird behaviour from $(window).load

Tags: jquery

I am sending a lot of data through socket.io when a user connects and rather than loading the page as and when a div has been loaded with the data I am trying to use $(window).load to wait until everything has been loaded.

If I hard refresh the website, clearing all the cache the website loads fine and everything fades in as normal but on a soft refresh the website finishes loading but nothing fades in.

Any ideas? Thanks

Here is the full code minus the unimportant bits:

```
socket.on('websiteLoad', function(data) {
    $('#pot_players, #pot_players_pics, #wheelInfo, #wheelArrow, #all_pot_items, #prev_win, #luck_win, #itemCounter, #timeCounter').hide().promise().done(function() {

        // Load Pot Data
        $('#pot_players').load('headers/pot.php')
        // 4 more .load here
        $('#wheelArrow').html('<img src="images/fade.png">')

        // Load Chart Data
        for (i=0;i<data.allData.chartData.length;i++) {
            // Data
        }

        // Load timers
        if (data.allData.itemData == null) {
            $('#itemCounter').html('<div class="time-seconds">0 /</div> 50 Items')
            $('#timeCounter').html('starting in 50 seconds...')
        }
        else {
            $('#itemCounter').html('<div class="time-seconds">' + data.allData.itemData + ' /</div> 50 Items')
            $('#timeCounter').html('starting in 50 seconds...')
        }

        // Load Luckiest Data
        if(data.allData.luckiestData == null) {
            var luckCon = '<div class="holder-l"><h3>Luckiest Player</h3><div class="info-hold-l"><h4>No One</h4>  <br>won <span>0</span>&#x1f353;<br>With <span>0%</span> chance!</div><div class="image-hold-l"><a href="#"><div class="image-effect"><img src="" alt=""></div></a></div></div>';
        }
        else {
            var luckCon = '<div class="holder-l"><h3>Luckiest Player</h3><div class="info-hold-l"><h4>' + data.allData.luckiestData.name + '</h4>  <br>won <span>' + data.allData.luckiestData.winnings + '</span>&#x1f353;<br>With <span>' + data.allData.luckiestData.percentage + '%</span> chance!</div><div class="image-hold-l"><a href="' + data.allData.luckiestData.profileLink + '"><div class="image-effect"><img src="' + data.allData.luckiestData.pic + '" alt=""></div></a></div></div>';
        }
        $('#luck_win').html(luckCon)
    });

    $('.welcome').css("display", "block").delay(5000).fadeOut();

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#pot_players, #pot_players_pics, #wheelInfo, #wheelArrow, #all_pot_items, #prev_win, #luck_win, #itemCounter, #timeCounter').fadeIn(1500);
        myChart.update();
    });
});
```

Comment: First thing that jumps out to me is that the callback for `$(window).load` exists within your `socket.on('websiteLoad', ...);` callback. Does the corresponding `websiteLoad` server event fire on soft refresh? What happens when you move your `$(window).load` logic outside of the socket event?

Comment: @maiorano84 I moved it outside the socket and it still loads randomly. I'm started to experience it not loading even when hard refreshing (inside or outside the socket). This emit happens on connection `io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {onLoad(socket);` however I am not sure what logic socket.io takes with soft refreshes and socket ids. onLoad is where I get all the information and emit it to the client.